# g++ combining libraries

Tags: g++, ld, unix-ar

So, I'm trying to incorporate the libpthread.a library into my own library.  But its giving me linker problems when I try and compile the code that uses it.  I compile it by doing the following:

```
g++ foo.cpp foo.o
ar x /usr/lib/libpthread.a
ar rcs libfoo.a *.o

g++ bar.cpp -o bar -L./ -lfoo
```

But I end up with a bunch of `undefined reference to 'pthread_stuff'`

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it by changing the compile arguments to:

`g++ -static bar.cpp -o bar -L./ -lfoo`

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your functions that use other C functions as `extern "C"` or else C++ name mangling would "distort" your names. More info: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc01name_mangling.htm

Comment: But why is this NOT a problem if I had linked it with `-lpthread`?

Comment: it *is*. Always. When it comes to linkage, at least.

Comment: Well... the errors don't happen when I JUST use `-lpthread`.  So... Thats weird to me.